# Как подключить xevil 4.0 к коду пайтон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как подключить к коду xevil 4.0 везде обыскал нечего нету, инфы ноль.
Очень секретная информация пж подскажите?

```
 def change_proxy(cls):
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', ip)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', port)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.https', ip)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.https_port', port)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', ip)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', port)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ftp', ip)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ftp_port', port)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', ip)
        cls.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', socks_port)
        cls.profile.update_preferences()
        cls.brawser.quit()
        cls.brawser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=cls.profile, options=cls.options)
change_proxy()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 def spisok_site():
        #byte
        brawser.get("http://localhost\8000")
        textteria = brawser.find_element_by_class_name("address").click()
        brawser.switch_to_window(2)
        brawser.close()
        textteria.send_keys("btc:nFDsdku8G43bdsGn40w95fjmcmpw97dCT8X")
        WebDriverWait(brawser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#recaptcha-anchor > div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
        time.sleep(30)
        brawser.find_element_by_css_selector( "#cim > form:nth-child(6) > f-1127b78c").click()
```

Comment: ну, судя по всему, api у них закрытое. Так что без костылей никак, проще уже использовать рукапчу или антигейт

Comment: Эх, понятно буду значит тесарект исползовать .